# how reasonable to estimate cpu cycles using bogomips?

Tags: linux, performance

If I've got a long-running process that uses, on average, 10% of the CPU as it does its job, and I run two copies of it in parallel, I can expect them to collectively use 20% of the CPU.  Or if I run one copy on a different CPU that's twice as fast, I can expect it to use 5% of that CPU.

What I'd like to do is get a handle on the CPU requirements of such a process, but in a reasonably CPU *in*dependent way, i.e. not as a percentage.

I'm wondering how meaningful it might be to assign a simple "cycles per second needed" number to such an app, by multiplying its CPU percentage by the bogomips number of the machine where I measured it.  That is, a process that uses 10% of the CPU on a machine with a bogomips value of 1000 could be said to require 100,000,000 (bogus) instructions per second.

(Disclaimers: Of course I know that bogomips are bogus, that instructions do not equal cycles, and that cycle and instruction timings are not at all comparable between disparate processor families.  I'm looking for rough, linear comparisons here, not precise counts.)

In some more detail: Suppose I've got a system with an assortment of long-running processes running on a possibly CPU-constrained machine.  I might want to predict, in advance, whether they'll all run without overloading the CPU.  Or I might want to implement checks (simple ones) that no process is using more CPU than it's supposed to.  I'm willing to empirically measure the performance of each process in advance, to help me make these predictions and implement these checks.  What I'm exploring here is, what's the right unit to measure the performance in?

For example, today I might be running processes A, B, D, E, and H on processor X.  I might observe that the percent of CPU used by the processes is 10, 5, 1, 5, and 20%, respectively. 10+5+1+5+20 is 41, and 41 is comfortably less than 100, so I'm fine.

But tomorrow I might want to run processes A, B, C, H, and J on a different processor Y running at half the clock rate.  Even if I also know something about the performance of processes C and J, it just seems unnecessarily messy to try to do the math based on percentages, when the CPU (that the percentages are of) is a moving target.

As mentioned, I might also want to assign an explicit CPU "budget" to each long-running process, and for sanity's sake I might want that budget to stay reasonably valid over time.  That is, I might want to say that process A is only allowed to use 100,000,000 cycles per second.  If it ever uses 150,000,000, something is wrong.  But if I move everything to a 2x faster CPU tomorrow, I do not want process A to be able to get away with using twice as much, because I might have in mind to use the extra CPU power for other processes.

Finally, if this has made any sense, and if multiplying by bogomips is not a good way of doing what I'm trying to do, does anyone have any better ideas?

(Oh, and one more disclaimer: the question obviously gets more complicated for multi-processor machines, and multi-core processors.  I'll worry about those additional wrinkles later, not today.)

Answer (score 0):

*Completely* unreasonable.  No, seriously.  Indeed, removing bogomips was proposed, precisely because they're meaningless, but was overridden because it broke some users' functionality: https://lwn.net/Articles/627930/ (search for 'bogomips').